# How To Hide The Last Top Nav Tab in SharePoint 2010

Tags: navigation, top-link-bar

I have found how to hide the first top nav tab, but I need to hide the last one as well. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: I think you need to add some details, what does "Last Top Nav Tab" mean to you? :)

Comment: On the following picture -> http://officeimg.vo.msecnd.net/en-001/files/653/712/ZA102099871.jpg I was able to hide "Home, but I want also to hide "Finance".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your masterpage and add the following css code:

```
/* Hides the top navigation links */     
.s4-tn { display:none !important; }
```

Unfortunately there is no setting in the site settings where could hide it.

Here is my favorite overview of all css classes in sharepoint 2010:
http://sp2010notes.wordpress.com/sharepoint-2010-css-chart/

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to thinks of some workaround though.